# Java 8 generic Retry if specific exception

Tags: java, spring, exception

I'm finding myself writing alot of retry loops that look like

```
    int triesRemaining = 3;

    while (triesRemaining > 0) {
        try {
            <MY FUNCTION CALL>
            LOGGER.info("success");
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                triesRemaining--;
                LOGGER.info(e.getMessage() + " trying again. Tries Remaining: " + triesRemaining);
            } else {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if (triesRemaining == 0) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed over too many times");
    }
```

I want to write a generic function that accepts a Lambda and only retries on a specific error (in the above case thats `SocketTimeoutException`). I've seen some functions that accept a `Runnable` which is fine, but they don't seem to allow limiting to specific exceptions.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to org.springframework.retry

There is an annotation @Retryable which corresponding to your need. You can specify the type of exception to retry and configure the number of attempt, etc...

Comment: Dear OP, for future it will be not worse to  mention in tags that you are using `spring` framework

Answer (score 2):

Well it's already done. It also accepts list of exceptions on which you want to retry. It also provides linear/exponential retry strategies.
Have a look https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying

A simple example from it's **readme**, you can compose and use a retryer like:-

```
Callable<Boolean> callable = new Callable<Boolean>() {
public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    return true; // do something useful here
}};

Retryer<Boolean> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder()
    .retryIfResult(Predicates.<Boolean>isNull())
    .retryIfExceptionOfType(IOException.class)
    .retryIfRuntimeException()
    .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.stopAfterAttempt(3))
    .build();

try {
  retryer.call(callable);
} catch (RetryException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem of just making this function to accept a `Runnable` argument and then run it in `<MY FUNCTION CALL>`?

```
public static void retry(Runnable r) {
      // ...
      while (triesRemaining > 0) {
        try {
            r.run();
            LOGGER.info("success");
            break;
        } 
      // ...
}
```

then call it (if you prefer - with a lambda):

```
    retry(() -> {
        connectToServer();
        // todo what-ever-you-want
    });
```

Comment: I want to only catch specific exceptions

Comment: TBH I do not understand how does this statement relate to my suggestion :) I've just omitted rest part of your code, which I marked as "// ... ".

Comment: Because I want the function to generically accept the exception class, which I was having trouble with. But I looked at guava-retrying and saw `Class<? extends Throwable>` which was the solution to my problem

Comment: I still do not understand what do you mean :-D

Comment: The function should have the signature `void retry(Runnable run, Class<? extends Throwable> exception, int numTries)`. But we're all good here.

Comment: This claim wasn't specified in question. If it would, sure I would prepare needed function specification. Please consider making your questions more detailed, people can not read your thoughts

Comment: I want to write a generic function that accepts a Lambda **and only retries on a specific error**

Comment: I understand it now, but if you know exact function specification, you **should** mention it in your **question**, but not in comments below given answers

Comment: I didn't know it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe):

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy()
  .retryOn(SocketTimeoutException.class)
  .withMaxRetries(3);

Failsafe.with(retryPolicy)
  .onRetry((c, f, ctx) -> log.warn("Failure #{}. Retrying.", ctx.getExecutions()))
  .onFailure(e -> LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e))
  .run(() -> myFunctionCall());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for pure Java based solution. Based on assumption, I would say Java 8 uses functional interface, an interface with single abstract method. I would create a new **RetryCommand** class that has a **run** method which takes in a function.